# PHP Function to redirect based on time and day

Tags: php, wordpress, strpos

I have a WP restaurant site that has a lunch menu and a dinner menu. They are /lunch-menu/ and /dinner-menu/ respectively. I also have a page called /menu/ that is designed to redirect the user to the correct menu page based on time/day.

The lunch menu is available Monday - Friday from 11am - 3pm. So, I check the day:

```
function is_weekday() {
    $day_of_week = date('N'); // 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)
    return ($day_of_week >= 1 && $day_of_week <= 5);
}
```

then check the time

```
// Function to check if the current time in Central Time Zone is before 3 PM
function is_before_3pm() {
    $timezone = 'America/Chicago'; // Central Time Zone
    $current_time = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    $time_3pm = new DateTime('3:00 PM', new DateTimeZone($timezone));

    return $current_time < $time_3pm;
}
```

then redirect any non-admin users

```
// Redirect users who are not logged in as admin based on current day and time in Central Time Zone
add_action('template_redirect', 'menu_redirect');

function menu_redirect() {
    // Check if the user is not logged in as admin
    if (!current_user_can('activate_plugins')) { // Change the capability to the appropriate admin capability if needed.
        // Check if the current URL contains '/menu/'
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/menu/') !== false) {
            // Check if it's a weekday and before 3 PM in Central Time Zone
            if (is_weekday() && is_before_3pm()) {
                wp_redirect('/lunch-menu/');
                exit;
            } else {
                wp_redirect('/dinner-menu/');
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works great. But, I am having an issue when using a link pointing directly to /lunch-menu/ or /dinner-menu/. The user is getting redirected. It doesn't happen if I type one of those URLs directly into my browser. Only if I add a link to an element that *should* point to one of them specifically.

I'm using WordPress and Elementor. And I tried setting the link on the element to both the internal -> content -> lunch-menu and putting the entire hard-coded link in. Same behavior in both cases.

Can anyone tell me why? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: When I inspect the page and look specifically at an element that *should* point to /lunch-menu/, I see this link in there:

<div data-ha-element-link="{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/thefulldomain.com\/lunch-menu\/&quot;,&quot;is_external&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;nofollow&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;custom_attributes&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" 

so not sure why it is redirecting since /menu/ doesn't exist in the string.

Comment: I'm often looking at menus _before_ going to a restaurant, and often not during the specific meal period. If I'm understanding you, if I plan to go to this restaurant for dinner but decide this at 1:00 in the afternoon, I can't get to the dinner menu, only the lunch menu, is that right?

Comment: And further, if Google indexes during the lunch hour, they won't find a dinner menu?

Comment: @ChrisHaas - that's exactly why I want both the /lunch-menu/ and /dinner-menu/ pages to work. If you click on the /menu/ link, it takes you to a page that shows the currently active menu but also shows you which menu you are looking at and has a link to the other menu. I was planning on adding /menu/ to the norobots.txt file and having Google index lunch-menu and dinner-menu.

Comment: Okay, that does make sense, but I still think that you are trying to help users more than needed, and you are also losing a free SEO page, the "menus page", which could hold links to both along with whatever text you want. I've just never heard a person say "Ugh, I had to click twice to get to the dinner menu page". If you really want to solve this for users, I'd recommend introducing a UI such as a dropdown menu that allows them to self-select the specific menu. These are all just my personal observations and recommendations, although they are backed by several decades of experience.

Comment: Woohoo! Figured it out. It was a (stupid) mistake on my part. I had used an inner section in Elementor and applied the links to each column. I failed to realize that the main section (that holds the inner section) had a link on it as a previous attempt. Whew. Feels good to have figured it out. But that's two hours of my life I won't be getting back. :)